# Evento de boton requiere dos click

Tags: jquery

### Tengo un formulario con botones que estand entro de un panel, el contenido lo creo dinamicamente, y el evento no responde con un solo  click.

```js
$("#canilla1").click(function(event) {
$('input[value=SELECCIONAR]').on('click', function(){ 
    cliente = $("#codcli").val();
 
 var CC = $( '#cc' ).is(':checked');
```

Asi empieza el codigo, es decir el sistema funciona perfectamente, pero aparentemente como es un evento dentro de otro requiere dos click, de hecho si hago click dentro del panel, luego con un click se acciona el boton.:

```js
var contenido='<div class="col-sm-3" > '+
         '<div class="panel panel-danger" font-size:30px; name="canillas" >'+
          '<div class="panel-heading" name="unica"id="'+item.idcanilla+ '">CANILLA '+item.idcanilla+ '  ----           '+ item.nombre+'</div>'+
          '<div class="panel-body">'+
        '<table id="tcanilla" class="canilla">'+
   ' <thead>'+
   
    '</thead>'+
    '<tbody>'+
    '<tr>'+
    '<td>Estado</td>'+
    '<td>'+item.estado+'</td></tr>'+
    '<input type="button" class="btn-primary" value="SELECCIONAR" name="'+item.idbarril+'" id="'+item.idcanilla+'"'+

    
  
  
   ' </tbody>'+
  '</table>'+
      '     </div></div></div> ' +
      '  </div>';
      $(contenido).appendTo("#canilla1");
```

El contenido dinamico es ese, es un panel dentro de una columna 3 para que entren 4 a lo ancho. A su vez el boton esta dentro de un table dentro de esa columna. Y canilla1 es un div en el html principal.
Porque si pongo

```
$('input[value=SELECCIONAR]').on('click', function(){
```

Solamente el codigo de arriba el evento no me escucha.

Como podria resolver ese problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás haciendo mal la referencia al momento de asignar el evento.

```
$('#canilla1').on('click', 'input[type=button]', function(){
    ...
});
```

De esta forma delegas el evento click a todos los `input[type=button]` dentro de `#canilla1`.